No FFmpeg on Stack Overflow?
This question shouldn't be locked, ffmpeg is a tool primarily used by programmers. I'm pretty sure a new mod did this (one unfamiliar with the land programming bash scripts). It was open for 9 years prior and had a lot of traction.
How to create a video from images with FFmpeg?
If you don't unlock it at least change the reason to something accurate.

CLI != "programming". Perhaps you're unfamiliar with the land of literally every non-programmer who uses the shell. Power users, system administrators, etc.

Why does it need unlocking? Are you looking to edit one of the answers or the question itself, or is it just so you can vote?

The tag wiki for FFmpeg has, since before the question was asked, a line saying to take command line questions to Super User or Video Production and not Stack Overflow.

@Warcupine i can see why, they might actually know whats up lol

"they might actually know whats up" and this is exactly why it's off-topic here: because the experts on FFMPEG command-line usage are over there, not here.

just to be clear -- this means that NO questions regarding usage of ANY commands should be in stackoverflow? including compiling tools like gcc? if not where exactly is that line @RyanM

As a note, you are giving off a very strong "I'm right and everyone else is wrong" vibe here; that is never well received here. As a community we're always open to new ideas and opinions, but you also have to be open too; it's a two-way street.

@user2918098: your lols and lmaos are belittling and not appreciated.

If it is primarily used by programmers it is on topic. I'm not familiar with FFmpeg but it seems like the command line users would be video production people and programming people's common interactions would be with the API. Something like pip uses command lines but is exclusively in the programming realm and thus on topic at Stack Overflow.

"you are not even a mod lmao" I fail to see how that's relevant. The site is made.up of a community of users who contribute and curate; the moderator team make up a tiny percentage of the community. You haven't even read the [tour] yet, so I'm wondering how you can claim to know what is, and isn't, appropriate on site when you haven't read the initial guidance on what the site ([so]) even is...

"this means that NO questions regarding usage of ANY commands should be in stackoverflow? including compiling tools like gcc? if not where exactly is that line" No, programming command-line tools (such as gcc) are on-topic.  Please see What topics can I ask about here? for a detailed description of where the line is, but most relevantly (emphasis added), it must be "a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development" (ffmpeg is not "unique to software development").

Related: Why is FFmpeg better discussed at Super User?

Note that the question being closed and the question being locked are two completely different things.

"If you don't unlock it at least change the reason to something accurate." - I wish Stack Overflow was still a site where there wouldn't be thousands of incoming questions daily and there were still a lot of people willing to do curation so things could be micromanaged to perfection. Those days are long gone. People close quick, not well.

See also: Are questions about tar off-topic on Stack Overflow?; Why do we have tags for off-topic topics?; Stop randomly determining questions about server software to be off-topic: write proper guidelines or leave them alone; What is the correct SE site for a question about sfdisk?; Why is this not a relevant question for Stack Overflow?; ...

The line really is much clearer than people keep saying it is. When you use the tool, are you inherently writing code? Is the question specifically about writing code such that the code will use the tool? If you're installing something, will installing it help you to write code?

I'm a programmer. I've used the ffmpeg command line tool. I've never directly used the ffmpeg API. I've also used Notepad, vi, nano, linux, macOS, Windows, Firefox, and bash. Just because I've used those and I'm a programmer doesn't mean those tools are primarily used by programmers. The same goes for ffmpeg: it's a video and audio processing tool, not a tool primarily used by programmers.
This question should remain closed. It is not about programming. Being open for 9 years isn't a justification keeping it open any longer.

Bash is a programming language according to stackoverflow, so yes bash is primarily used by programmers. The actual answer I was looking for is to ask on Super User. Also you are missing the keyword "primarily" in your answer, most users of the things you mentioned are not programmers -- unlike ffmpeg i would argue. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28693737/is-bash-a-programming-language

@user2918098 A single CLI command isn't bash programming.

ping is a command I can use in Bash. I guarantee you that ping has been used by more people who have no clue how to write any useful program in Bash than people who do. Source: I have no clue how to write any useful program in Bash. But I can use command-line tools like ping or netstat. So can many people. My father can use ping and he probably would have a hard time telling Windows from Linux.

@user2918098 I never claimed I had done bash scripting, simply that I had used bash. Regardless, shell scripting isn't implicitly on-topic either. "Also you are missing the keyword "primarily" in your answer," I use it twice, actually. The question is about the ffmpeg CLI tool, which requires no code to use, and is not primarily used by programmers. A question about the libavcodec library could be on topic.

When is it OK to ask shell scripting questions on SO? ; Why is this question about shell programming closed as "not about programming or software development"?.
